# Initializers as actual parameters of vector constructors

Tags: c++

I need to create a two-dimensional array using the vector vectors, and to initialize the row, you need to use initializers as actual parameters of vector constructors. Can you tell me what mean "initializers as actual parameters of vector constructors"?

Comment: Probably not.  If this is homework, ask your instructor.

Comment: Is this about initializer lists maybe? It would help to have more context for that fragment.

Comment: Where did you get that statement from? I can't find it in the official reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: @it's hometask of my teacher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array_2d(rows, std::vector<int>(cols, 0));
```

This creates a rows * cols 2D array where each element is 0. The default value is std::vector(cols, 0) which means each row has a vector which has cols number of element, each being 0.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell me what mean "initializers as actual parameters of vector constructors"?

**Construct a 1D vector**

```
// Construct a 1D vector with the elements {10, 20, 30, 40}
std::vector<int> v1 = {10, 20, 30, 40};
```

**Construct a 2D vector**

```
// Construct a 2D vector with 2 rows and 3 colomns.
// First row has the elements {10, 20, 30}
// Second row has the elements {40, 50, 50}
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2 = {{10, 20, 30}, {40, 50, 60}};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/E1v38P)